# How to configure Rails3.1 engine to use its application layout and scss?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I created a simple engine with rails 3.1.rc.1
All is fine.

When I change anything in the engines app/assets and app/views/layout application layout file, it doesn't get loaded.

But when I make changes in the dummy app inside test/dummy/app/views or assets file, it gets reflected.

Couldn't figure out a way on how to tell the engine to use its own assets/layout rather than the dummy app?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this for the layout ?

```
module MyEngine
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    layout "application" # or the name of the layout to use in the application
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check your code

1. if your asset pipeline is enabled?
   config/application.rb

   config.assets.enabled = true
2. In rails3.1, app/view/layout add stylesheet & javascript should be like:

   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "mystylesheetname" %>

   <%= javascript_include_tag "myjavascriptname" %>
3. You can add additional (fully qualified) paths to the pipeline in config/application.rb.

   config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/mystylesheet"
4. If you access image in the assets/images on your views, you should do like this:

   <%= image_tag "rails.png" %>
5. Empty the folder tmp\cache, rails s again

Answer (score 0):

@ivanLee, @Pixoo

I'd put this question when Rails in 3.1.rc.1

Later with the stable Rails 3.1.x released, I re-generated the plugin inside the same engine and overwritten the changed codes. And it works without any question by default.

But @ivanLee,

your tips might solve the issue I'm having is that I cannot use the SASS variable set in other files via the sprocket.

And if I totally go with the SASS path, using `@import somesass_or_sass_partial`, it works in development but when I do `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:compile` the build fails with weird error.